# Is there a way to disable Hibernate optimistic locking?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class VersionedDo {
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;
    ...
}
```

I want to update this entity without version increment in the some cases. Is there any way to do it without direct SQL update?

Answer (score 0):

From Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) :

> Your application is forbidden from altering the version number set by Hibernate.
>
> To artificially increase the version number, see the documentation for properties `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` or `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENTcheck` in the Hibernate Entity Manager reference documentation.

Therefore, using Hibernate, I guess you cannot force a version field to keep its original value when updating. You can only do the opposite.

You'll have to use a classic SQL query and don't forget to "refresh" your Hibernate object if needed.

Comment: But I don't want to alter version I just want to disable version increment in some cases.

Comment: Hibernate will automatically increment version, so if you want to keep previous value, that's "altering". At least, this is how I understand Hibernate doc about this.